# Rkhunter still relevant in 2022?

Tags: malware, rkhunter, rootkit

I tried using the RKHunter 1.4.6 (http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/rkhunter/rkhunter/1.4.6/rkhunter-1.4.6.tar.gz) in Ubuntu20.04 , it is around 4 years old , running it did not find any rootkits on my desktop. But i want to know if it is still relevant or good approach to use the rkhunter 1.4.6 for ubuntu20.04?